# Eclair Lightning Node With Core Version 18

Tags: lightning-network, eclair

When attempting to open channels in lightning network I get the following error:

```
signrawtransaction was removed in v0.18. Clients should transition to signrawtransactionwith key and signrawtransactionwith wallet (code: -32)
```

I know that `signrawtranaction` was a deprecated RPC call in version 0.17 but could still be used. However it was removed in version 0.18. Is there a workaround for this this for Eclair v0.2-beta9?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no workaround. According to [this github issue](https://github.com/ACINQ/eclair/issues/979), Eclair v0.2-beta9 is completely incompatible with Bitcoin Core 0.18. The next release of Eclair will fix this.